# How Do I share a complicated style from one Mapbox Account to another?

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-studio

I was looking at the [scenic](https://www.mapbox.com/designer-maps/#scenic) style, and I ended up copying it and modifying it in MapBox Studio.

What happened is that I edited it in my personal Account, and not my Organization's account.

How do I move or copy this modified style from my Account to another Account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll find your edited style on the [style overview page](https://www.mapbox.com/studio/styles/). Here you can click on the menu button besides your style and choose the "Download" option. A zip file will be downloaded which includes a style.json, a folder with additional icons and a license file.

You can upload this (unzipped) style.json to your organizations account by adding a new style and choosing "Upload a style" on the same overview page linked above.

Once the studio is open, you can then import all the images/svgs from the icon folder in the exported style.

Comment: And after uploading the style.json you can go into Studio and upload the image assets too.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing. I was expecting it would be more elegant than that. It's Bad UX that Mapbox Studio can't ingest the same format that it exports. For their own styles there is a simple link such as https://www.mapbox.com/studio/styles/add-style/mapbox/cj8gg22et19ot2rnz65958fkn/ for copying the style. I was expecting there would be something similar for Custom styles.